# How to create border in A4 page and fo:block rounded corner in using - XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

[image]

How to create a border in the A4 page and How to make rounded `fo:block`.

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-height="11.40in" page-width="8.27in" margin-top="0.30in" margin-bottom=".030in" margin-left="0.30in" margin-right="0.30in">
                <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin=".30in"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
            <fo:flow flow-name="body">
                <fo:block text-align="center" border="1pt" border-style="solid">
                    How to create rounded border
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested following XSL-FO file via FOP 2.5.

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-height="11.40in" page-width="8.27in" margin-top="0.30in" margin-bottom=".030in" margin-left="0.30in" margin-right="0.30in">
      <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin=".30in"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
    <fo:flow flow-name="body">
      <fo:block text-align="center" border="1pt" border-style="solid" fox:border-radius="10pt 15pt">
        Hello Word!
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

[The output snapshot]

[image: FOP 2.5 Output result]

[Sample command-line]
[image: FOP command-line example]

[Oxygen Transformation Scenario]

[image: Oxygen Transformation Scenario (FOP 2.4)]

[Oxygen 21.1 with FOP 2.3 build result]

[image: Oxygen 21.1 with FOP 2.3 build result]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can I use FOP 2.5 version with oxygen editor?

Comment: @Sam, yes the newest Oxygen bundles FOP 2.4 and it generates the same PDF. Apply  above transformation scenario.

Comment: I am using oxygen 21.1 version but not generate the same output. Can you please confirm oxygen editor version?

Comment: @Sam, I am using Oxygen 22.1 with the newest build-id 2020100710.

Comment: @Sam, Oxygen 21.1 bundles FOP 2.3. However I got the same result with above transformation scenario.

Comment: I have add one image `fox:border-radius="10pt 15pt"` this attribute not support showing the error my oxygen. Can you check my editing image?

Comment: It also occurs in my side and it is because Oxygen uses Antenna House oriented XSL-FO validator. Ignore the error message and apply transformation scenario. Then your can get the desired PDF using FOP.

Answer (score 0):

`fo:region-body` can have border properties.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_region-body.

---

Rounded corners are not in the XSL 1.1 Recommendation. However, your XSL formatter probably has an extension for rounded corners:

- Antenna House has `axf:border-radius` and related properties (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v70e/ahf-ext.html#axf.border-radius).
- FOP has `fox:border-*-*-radius` properties (see https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.5/extensions.html#rounded-corners).

Comment: Sir! I am using oxygen then not support `fox:border-*-*-radius` Can you tell me please that how to use `fox` with oxygen.